# Modify variable using a sub/function

Tags: vba, function, excel, user-defined-functions

I am trying to add a + sign in front of certain variables if they are positive.
ex:

```
Sub mySub()
    Dim cash As Variant 
End Sub
```

It works well if I do:

```
Dim plus As String
plus = "+"


If cash > 0 Then
  cash = plus & cash
  Else
  cash= cash
End If
```

But I was looking for a sub or function that would take all my variables and add a + sign in front of them if they are positive.

```
sub NewSub(i As Variant)
    If i > 0 Then
       i = plus & i
       Else
       i = i
    End If
End sub
```

But it doesn't seem to work as it doesn't show me anything (I then display my variables in a cell in excel). And a function doesn't work either.

Any ideas on how to create a sub/function to do that? Can I loop through my variables in any way ?

Comment: Did you envisaged to use Cell Formatting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, start using Option Explicit which forces you to explicitly declare every variable and will catch mismatch errors in the VBA editor and not at runtime.

Next, if you are going to change a numerical variable to a string by prefacing a 'plus' sign onto the left end then the original variable will have to be a variant type. If you want to pass a parameter into a sub procedure and have the sub change it then the parameter must be `ByRef`.

Alternately, you could push the variable into a function and return the new value.

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim cash As Variant, cash2 As Variant

    cash = 10
    Debug.Print cash    '10 (as number)

    AddPlus cash
    Debug.Print cash    '+10 (as string)

    cash = 10
    Debug.Print cash    '10 (as number)

    cash = udfAddPlus(cash)
    Debug.Print cash    '+10 (as string)

End Sub

Sub AddPlus(ByRef i As Variant)
    If i > 0 Then
       i = "+" & i
    Else
       i = i
    End If
End Sub

Function udfAddPlus(i As Variant)
    If i > 0 Then
       udfAddPlus = "+" & i
    Else
       udfAddPlus = i
    End If
End Function
```

The `Debug.Print` command sends output to the VBE's [Immediate window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278736.aspx).

Comment: It works perfectly thanks! Now would you know how to loop through the different variables with the function (like tell the function to start at cash1 and stop at cashn) ?

Comment: If I had a number of *cash* variables to declare, I would use an array. `dim cash(3) as variant` produces 4 variant variables; cash(0), cash(1), cash(2) and cash(3). Loop through from [LBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a7w1ac(v=vs.90).aspx) to [UBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278658.aspx).